How to set up request overload protection?
Is it necessary to config protection against DDoS-attacks and reduce load on the server, if application deployed on a virtual machine in the cloud? If I understand correctly, such servers have their own protection... However, I deployed java-application through NGINX (proxy server) and added the next parameters:
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=20r/s;
limit_req_status 429;

location / {
    limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;
    ...
}

How many correct this is solution, and is it necessary to do it?

With such settings, pages can break even in manual mode if you quickly click on tabs (because not all packets will be transmitted). The website typically has 4–6 resources per page,  but I have a big project, so I set rate=20r/s;
